# Type annotations: How to inherit from a Mixin of several classes and preserve static methods?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

> It is only the ts annotation problem, in js runtime works everything as expected.

For a multiple inheritance/mixin, we have a runtime method which takes classes/objects and creates compound(mixed) class.

```
class A {
    a: string
    static staticA: string
}
class B {
    b: string
    static staticB: string
}
class C extends mixin(A, B) {
    c: string
    static staticC: string
}
```

So our `mixin` method creates the mixed class which the `C` inherits. Now we have some annotation problems. Simple `mixin` declaration looks like this (*actually, `mixin` accepts also objects for `T1` and `T2`, but to make it simple I removed it from code*):

```
interface Constructor<T = {}> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;    
}

declare function mixin<T1 extends Constructor, T2 extends Constructor> (
    mix1: T1, 
    mix2: T2
): new (...args) => (InstanceType<T1> & InstanceType<T2>)
```

Unfortunately, the type returned by `mixin` looses static methods for `T1` and `T2`.

```
C. /* only 'staticC' is present in autocomplete */
let c = new C;
c. /* all - 'a', 'b' and 'c' are present in autocomplete */
```

I also tried to return the type `T1 & T2`, but get the error in `mixin(A, B)`

> [ts] Base constructors must all have the same return type.

Is there any solution for this?

---

### Final Solution

Thanks to @titian-cernicova-dragomir. I'm adding here my final solution, I have extended the annotation to support also objects, not only classes, hopefully it will be helpful for somebody.

```
// Extract static methods from a function (constructor)
type Statics<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

declare function mixin<
    T1 extends Constructor | object, 
    T2 extends Constructor | object,
    T3 extends Constructor | object = {},
    T4 extends Constructor | object = {},
    > (
        mix1: T1,
        mix2: T2,
        mix3?: T3,
        mix4?: T4,
    ): 
    (T1 extends Constructor ? Statics<T1> : {}) & 
    (T2 extends Constructor ? Statics<T2> : {}) &
    (T3 extends Constructor ? Statics<T3> : {}) &
    (T4 extends Constructor ? Statics<T4> : {}) &
    (new (...args: T1 extends Constructor ? ConstructorParameters<T1> : never[]) =>
        (T1 extends Constructor ? InstanceType<T1> : T1) &
        (T2 extends Constructor ? InstanceType<T2> : T2) &
        (T3 extends Constructor ? InstanceType<T3> : T3) &
        (T4 extends Constructor ? InstanceType<T4> : T4)
    );



class A {
    a: string
    static staticA: string
}
class B {
    b: string
    static staticB: string
}
const Utils = {
    log () {}
}
class C extends mixin(A, B, Utils) {
    c: string
    static staticC: string
}
C. // has 'staticA', 'staticB', 'staticC'
let c = new C;
c. // has 'a', 'b', 'c', 'log'
```

I have also added arguments support from the first class's constructor (if any).

`...args: T1 extends Constructor ? ConstructorParameters<T1> : never[]`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution to make the `mixin` annotation to support any number of arguments, currently I made 4, as it is enough for my case. Though our js `mixin` can accept any number of classes/objects to create mixed class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep you original `mixin` function as is, and just intersect the constructor you return with `T1` and `T2`

```
class A {
    a!: string
    static staticA: string
}
class B {
    b!: string
    static staticB: string
}
class C extends mixin(A, B) {
    c!: string
    static staticC: string
}

interface Constructor<T = {}> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

declare function mixin<T1 extends Constructor, T2 extends Constructor>(
    mix1: T1,
    mix2: T2
): {
    new(...args: any[]): (InstanceType<T1> & InstanceType<T2>)
} & T1 & T2

C.staticA
C.staticB
C.staticC
let c = new C;
c.a
c.b
c.c
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a!%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticA%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b!%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticB%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20mixin(A%2C%20B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c!%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticC%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20mixin%3CT1%20extends%20Constructor%2C%20T2%20extends%20Constructor%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mix1%3A%20T1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mix2%3A%20T2%0D%0A)%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20(InstanceType%3CT1%3E%20%26%20InstanceType%3CT2%3E)%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20T1%20%26%20T2%0D%0AC.staticA%0D%0AC.staticB%0D%0AC.staticC%0D%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20C%3B%0D%0Ac.a%0D%0Ac.b%0D%0Ac.c%0D%0A%0D%0A)

You mention you tried `T1 & T2` the problem with that approach is that would not change the constructor to return `(InstanceType<T1> & InstanceType<T2>)`. You must add this new signature to the constructor and the original classes as well.

Comment: Wow, that's it. Do you know why `T1 & T2 & (new(...args: any[]) => (InstanceType<T1> & InstanceType<T2>))` doesn't work, `mixin(A, B)` shows the error from question? But when `T1 & T2` are at the end, everything works. Thanks.

Comment: @tenbits not 100% sure why.. I'd have to look at the compiler code.. I found that weird too :).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your mixin mechanism... but it looks like the original version, rather than the updated version.

The example below taken from [TypeScript Mixins Part Three](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/11/typescript-mixins-part-three/) shows that static properties are handled in terms of the types and the runtime behaviour when you use this method of creating mixins.

## Mixins with Static Members

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Flies<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        static altitude = 100;
        fly() {
            console.log('Is it a bird? Is it a plane?');
        }
    };
}

function Climbs<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        static stickyHands = true;
        climb() {
            console.log('My spider-sense is tingling.');
        }
    };
}

class Hero {
    constructor(private name: string) {

    }
}

const HorseFlyWoman = Climbs(Flies(Hero));

const superhero = new HorseFlyWoman('Shelley');
superhero.climb();
superhero.fly();

console.log(HorseFlyWoman.stickyHands);
console.log(HorseFlyWoman.altitude);
```

## Runnable Version

Here is the transpiled version so you can see the output:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    }
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
function Flies(Base) {
    var _a;
    return _a = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
            __extends(class_1, _super);
            function class_1() {
                return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
            }
            class_1.prototype.fly = function () {
                console.log('Is it a bird? Is it a plane?');
            };
            return class_1;
        }(Base)),
        _a.altitude = 100,
        _a;
}
function Climbs(Base) {
    var _a;
    return _a = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
            __extends(class_2, _super);
            function class_2() {
                return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
            }
            class_2.prototype.climb = function () {
                console.log('My spider-sense is tingling.');
            };
            return class_2;
        }(Base)),
        _a.stickyHands = true,
        _a;
}
var Hero = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hero(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Hero;
}());
var HorseFlyWoman = Climbs(Flies(Hero));
var superhero = new HorseFlyWoman('Shelley');
superhero.climb();
superhero.fly();
console.log(HorseFlyWoman.stickyHands);
console.log(HorseFlyWoman.altitude);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this creates chainings, but I need to mix two different classes, so I can't modify them, to create something like `Flies`, `Climbs`.